# Getting SIGABRT error in main file

Tags: ios4

Am getting a SIGABRT error in my main file, and don't know what to do.

Maim file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

The  error message highlights the line reading:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

and reads: "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Can you tell me what's wrong, and what I need to do to get it compile?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you get this error while *compiling*, or while *running* your program? SIGABRT is a runtime error, so if you got it while compiling, then you may have broken the compiler itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error elsewhere in your application. You'll have to run the debugger and step through the screen that causes the crash until you reach the line where it jumps to `SIGABRT` in `main`. Usually it'll have something to do with memory management (over-releasing an object and then accessing it) or improper initialisation of `UIKit` objects, which `UIKit` then attempts to render (which includes returning an object of the wrong type, or accidentally assigning the wrong `tag` to a UI element so it's sent a message it can't handle). If it's improper initialisation, though, you should get an additional error printed to inform you of that.

*EDIT:* Actually, yes, you mention it can't compile? SIGABRT is a signal sent to the *running application*, so I don't see how it can come up during compilation.

Comment: Found the problem. Had an incomplete implementation of the UIPicker Datasource protocol. Added the required method and it compiled fine. Thank you.

Comment: No worries :) If you added the protocol to your class definition `@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource>`, the compiler would have issued you a warning for that as well. Note that it's good to try and eliminate all compiler warnings, not just the errors.