# "SIGABRT" in main() method

Tags: iphone, ios5

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707217/getting-sigabrt-error-in-main-file) question and wanted to reply to a comment by "darvids0n" in his answer to that question, but could not do that. So I posted this question.

I got the same kind of error and was getting it even if I created a new project and clicked on the "Run" button. Don't know what I am missing. I use Xcode 4.2.

Any help is greatly appreciated... Thank you..

Comment: SIGABRT errors are very rarely (never?) the actual error message that we need to see. Likely, there's an "unhandled exception" somewhere. We need that message, as well as the code that triggers it, in order to do anything for you.

Comment: I suggest you fill out your question with your actual issues, as you can't guarantee a linked question will always be there for future readers. :)

Answer (score 1):

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

}

This is your main method...If “SIGABRT” in main() method in main method that means not that error is in main method but it can be anywhere in your project...So I think you have to debug your project...Or plz check nib file may not be load properly...ALL THE BEST!!!

Comment: Hi Nishit, actually the app crashes at the very beginning itself. It doesn't go beyond the main() method. By the way, here's the main() method that I have: 'int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}'

Comment: Ya this one is also feasible method as a main method....so I think in MainWindow.xib problem should be to Bind...can you send me the Log related to crash...??

Comment: I have solved this issue. I just ran the "Clean" option from the menu and specified the rootViewController in the "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" method. Don't know if this is the right way, but it worked! Heres the code that I added after "self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];"

    SearchScreen *srch = [[SearchScreen alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = srch;

SearchScreen is the sole class that I have in my project. I created an instance of that class and assigned it as the rootViewController.

Thanks everyone for the help!!